# C++ Function Return Issue

Tags: c++, function, return, overloading

I am trying to make a function that can return the size of an array that can be different data types. I believe the expression (sizeof(z)/sizeof(*z))) returns the memory allocated to z divided by the memory size of the data type. The following code is my attempt to overload the function and return the size of the array as an integer. When I run the expression in the main function it works, but when I try to pass the array to the function I do not get the correct values and not sure what I am doing wrong. 68 / 4 = 17 which is the correct size of the array.

(1) outputs sizeof(z) and sizeof(*z) in the size function

(2) expression in main function

(3) outputs sizeof(z) in the main function

(4) outputs sizeof(*z) in the main function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//
int size(int *data){
  cout << sizeof(data) << ", " << sizeof(*data) << ", ";
  return((sizeof(data))/(sizeof(*data)));
}
int size(char *x){return(sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));}
int size(float *x){return(sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));}
int size(double *x){return(sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));}
int size(short int *x){return(sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));}
int size(long int *x){return(sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x));}

int main(){

  double x[9];
  int z[17];
  char k[29];

  cout << "(1) Size : " << size(z) << endl;
  cout << "(2) Size : " << (sizeof(z)/sizeof(*z)) << endl;
  cout << "(3) Size : " << sizeof(z) << endl;
  cout << "(4) Size : " << sizeof(*z) << endl;
  cout << "(5) Size : " << size(z) << endl;
  cout << "(6) Size : " << size(k) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
(1) Size : 8, 4, 2
(2) Size : 17
(3) Size : 68
(4) Size : 4
(5) Size : 8, 4, 2
(6) Size : 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a common mistake:

```
char* a // is a pointer
char  b[] // is an array
```

when using:

```
char b[5]; // is an array of 5 bytes
sizeof(b); // 5
// but
char* a = b;
sizeof(a); // 8 (x64)
```

the last `sizeof(a)` is giving you the sizeof `char *` which is a pointer.

You can pass the name of an Array as a Pointer to the `size()` function, but in that function, the argument is treated as Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

An array decays to a pointer when you pass it to another function, so `sizeof(arr)` will give you the actual amount of memory allocated, only in the scope of the function in which `arr` was declared.